# `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` launching search action in Google app

Tags: android, android-intent

I was trying to launch an `Intent` which will launch a browser and search query on Google. But the problem is that it is directly launching the search query on Google app instead of any browser. I have tested this on emulator and also in my Android device.

**My Approach :**

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY,queryText);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can open browser using below intent

```
    try{
        String escapedQuery = URLEncoder.encode("Android developer", "UTF-8");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/#q=" + escapedQuery);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```